# Cast date string to Date object

Tags: ruby

I have a date string like following

> ( Tue, Jan 29, 2013)

How can I convert it to a Date object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'time'
dt = "( Tue, Jan 29, 2013)"
Time.parse(dt) #=> 2013-01-29 00:00:00 -0800
Date.parse(dt) #=> #<Date: 2013-01-29 ((2456322j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date'
dt=" ( Tue, Jan 29, 2013) "
Date.parse dt
# => #<Date: 2013-01-29 ((2456322j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

Date.parse(dt).to_s
# => "2013-01-29"
```